# Is there a way to Open A New Browser and not a new tab using webbrowser.open

Tags: python

I had the import and everything, and my code works, but it just adds the link i want in a new tab. I want the link to appear in a new window. The webbrowser.open_new doesn't work for me and just puts it in a tab. Is there a way to Fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

> webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)¶
>   Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. **If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible**. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible (note that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable).

So yes, just set the parameter "new" to 1